# Jquery load set of images from XML file

Tags: jquery, xml, image, flash, prettyphoto

hi i've got a script like this :

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.prettyPhoto();
    $.get("xml/kategoria1.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
        lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
      openLightbox(lightbox)
    });
});
});

function openLightbox(path) {
    $.prettyPhoto.open(path);
```

And it opens only a single image from xml, i want to open all images from xml called lightbox.

here is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<images>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image1.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image1.jpg">
<lightbox>Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image1.jpg</lightbox>

</image>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image2.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image2.jpg">
<lightbox>Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image2.jpg</lightbox>

</image>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image3.jpg" lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image3.jpg">
<lightbox>Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image3.jpg</lightbox>
</image>


</images>
```

Please for help.

Greetings Krystian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your code, you will open a lightbox for each image.

What you should do is creating an array containing all the images, and then pass it to the lightbox.

Instead of this:

```
$('image',xml).each(function(i) {
        lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
      openLightbox(lightbox)
    });
```

Do this:

```
images = new Array();
$('image',xml).each(function(i) {
      image = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
      images.push(image);
    });
openLightbox(images)
```

Comment: you are amazing :D it works ;) i have a other question. beacause i'm sending function from flash and i send from there a single image. And i wan't to open the image it is a "path" and then the rest of images from xml

Comment: Let's say your first image coming from your flash code is called `flashImage`

Just do `images.push(flashImage);` after `images = new Array();`.

Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Man you are the best:D!! it working perfectly :D
Sorry for questions but i wan't to ask if i do like u tell me it work but it duplicate one photo it is not that bad but is it possible to remove one??

Comment: and sorry for another question but i wan't to do it good, it opens a path from flash and then all pictures from the begining from xml, and is it possible to do that when i'm clicking to thumbnail and it open's a path image and when i click prev or next button to start changing image from this path image